# returning a String when getting error: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I can't work out how to return a string from a function in Dart (a Flutter app).

I am using SharedPreferences to capture input from the user. I have two functions, one to save preferences:

```
    save(key, value) async {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setString(key, value);
      print('saved $value');
  }
```

and one to read preferences:

```
    read(key) async {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final value = prefs.getString(key) ?? 0;
      print('$value');
}
```

This is working, but when I try to replace the print line with a return:

```
    read(key) async {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final value = prefs.getString(key) ?? 0;
      return('$value');
}
```

to return a string for the value, it throws an error:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'

I have tried calling it many MANY different ways, but can't figure out what I assume is an incredibly basic problem. I noticed in some posts that this is a suggested solution, which works to print out the value, but I don't want to print it, i want it as a String variable:

```
read(mykey).then((value) => '$value');
```

I need to combine the value with other some other string values and make some minor manipulations (so printing it isn't helpful)

### UPDATE

I have defined the function as @Stijn2210 suggested, but am still having problems getting the output i need.

```
  Future<String> read(key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final value = await prefs.getString(key) ?? '';
    return value;
  }
```

When I call this function from my app (this is a simplified snippet):

```
void onDragEnd(DraggableDetails details, User user) {
    final minimumDrag = 100;
    Future<String> myvalue;
    if (details.offset.dx > minimumDrag) {
      user.isSwipedOff = true;
      save(user.imgUrl, 'Dog');
}
    myvalue = read(user.imgUrl);
    print(myvalue);
```

It's printing :

> Instance of 'Future'

Whereas I want myvalue to be 'Dog'... Appreciate any insights!!

Really appreciate your answer @Stijn2202

Solution was to edit the method definition:
`Future<void> onDragEnd(DraggableDetails details, User user) async`
and then call the read function from the method with this:

`final String myvalue = await read(user.imgUrl);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getString` is a Future, which you can handle by using `await` or as you are doing, using `then`

However, in my opinion using `await` is your better option. This would look like this:

```dart
Future<String> getMyString() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final value = await prefs.getString(key) ?? ''; 
  // Don't use 0, since it isnt an int what you want to return
  return value;
}
```

EDIT:

based on your code snippet, this is how you should call your `read` method:

```dart
Future<void> onDragEnd(DraggableDetails details, User user) async {
    final minimumDrag = 100;
    if (details.offset.dx > minimumDrag) {
      user.isSwipedOff = true;
      save(user.imgUrl, 'Dog');
    }
    final String myvalue = await read(user.imgUrl);
    print(myvalue);
}
```

Now I'm not sure if `onDragEnd` is actually allowed to be `Future<void>`, but let me know if it isn't

Comment: REALLY appreciate the quick reply, and thanks for the Future<String> advice. I am no longer getting an error, but how do I convert this "Future<String>" to a "String" variable that I can use? When i try to use it I just see "Instance of 'Future<String>'"

Comment: Ah yes, I shouldve mentioned that you need to await your function in your code where you call it. Can you add a snippet of code where you call `read(key)`?

Comment: thanks @Stijn2210 I have updated the question with more info....

Comment: Appreciate it mate!

Comment: Perfect!! I just had to also add an async to the function too... @Stijn2210 THANK YOU SO MUCH... Seriously man... I have been stuck for hours on this, so really appreciate your expertise!! Wishing you all the best!!

Comment: @Calamari I gotchu! reach out to me if you run into anything else

Answer (score 0):

Just await for the value. It will return Dog and not instance of Future.

`String someName=await myvalue;`

As the value is Future, await keyword will wait until the task finishes and return the value

Comment: The `onDragEnd` must be then marked as `async`and have to be of type `Future<void>`